# Is there a way in google script to access files inside a folder through a shortcut to the folder by folder name?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I added a shortcut to a folder in my drive to a shared folder in the work environment. In script, I have access the the shared folder, but `folder.searchFolders` cannot find the shortcut folder.

Edit: Sorry for the lack of details, here is an overview of my use case:

I have a root folder called Root, and its static in my app. inside this, there are lots of shortcuts to external folders. My app knows the name of the specific shortcut(folder name) and want to get a reference to the folder by searching the name in order to access all the files inside the folder.

Root

---Shortcut:aaa

---Shortcut:bbb

Currently, I can get access to the shurtcut by `getFilesByName("aaa")`, but this is as far as I could get, cannot find the files in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the folder of the shortcut in the specific folder using Google Apps Script.

For this, how about this answer?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the shortcut file is retrieved using Drive service. In this case, please use `searchFiles` instead of `searchFolders`. And the mimeType of `application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut` is included for searching the shortcut files in the search query.

#### Sample script:

```
const folderId = "###";  // Please set the folder ID.

const params = "title = 'samples_for_SlideSearcher' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut'";
const files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).searchFiles(params);
while (files.hasNext()) {
  const f = files.next();
  console.log(f.getName())
}
```

- In this case, the shortcut name is retrieved.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the shortcut file is retrieved using Drive API. When the shortcut file is retrieved using Drive service, in the current stage, it seems that the target information of shortcut cannot be included. So in order to retrieve the target information, I would like to propose this pattern as an another method.

#### Sample script:

When you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```
const folderId = "###";  // Please set the folder ID.

const params = `title = 'samples_for_SlideSearcher' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut' and '${folderId}' in parents`;
const items = Drive.Files.list({fields: "items(id,title,shortcutDetails)", q: params, includeItemsFromAllDrives: true, supportsAllDrives: true}).items;
const res = items.map(e => ({id: e.id, name: e.title, shortcutDetails: e.shortcutDetails}));
console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

- In this case, the following values are retrieved.

  ```
  [
    {
      "id": "###",  // File ID of the shortcut.
      "name": "###",  // Filename of the shortcut.
      "shortcutDetails": {
        "targetMimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",  // Folder ID of the target folder.
        "targetId": "###"  // Folder ID of the target folder.
      }
    }
  ]
  ```
- About `const items = Drive.Files.list({fields: "items(id,title,shortcutDetails)", q: params, includeItemsFromAllDrives: true, supportsAllDrives: true}).items;`, when the file list cannot be retrieved, by adding the drive ID, please modify to `const items = Drive.Files.list({fields: "items(id,title,shortcutDetails)", q: params, includeItemsFromAllDrives: true, supportsAllDrives: true, corpora: "drive", driveId: "###"}).items;` and test it again.

### Note:

- In the current stage, Drive service can use the shared Drive.
- If you want to search by containing a value in the filename, please modify `title = 'samples_for_SlideSearcher'` to `title contains 'samples_for_SlideSearcher'`

### References:

- [Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive)
- [Search query terms](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list)

Comment: Sorry, what Im interested is how to find files through a shortcut. I added more details about what I really need.

Comment: @ChaosBB Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I had thought that you wanted to retrieve the shortcut files using the shortcut name. I couldn't understand about `what I really need.` from your initial question. I deeply apologize for this. About your updated question, in this case, how about using the pattern2 I added as another method? In this case, the target information of the shortcut file can be retrieved. So the target folder ID can be retrieved. About this, when you have an issue, please tell me.

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to get the id to the folder through the targetId now. Im curious. Is this same type of data not accessible through DriveApp?

Comment: @ChaosBB Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that there are no prepared methods for directly retrieving the target information of shortcut in the Drive service of `DriveApp`. But the shortcut has been recently added. So I want to believe that such method will be added in the future update. If you want to propose to add such methods in Drive service, how about requesting it to the Google issue tracker as the future request? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)