# I have a shared google drive folder . Is there any methods to list all the files in my google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I had a link of shared folder that is not in my google drive. It is a shared folder. Would i able to lists all the files in my google sheets using script editor?
I've used this code but it is only applicable for the folder that is in my google drive.

```
function listFolderContents() {
  var foldername = 'your-folder';
  var folderlisting = 'listing of folder ' + foldername;
  
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername)
  var folder = folders.next();
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(folderlisting);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow( ['name', 'link'] );
  
  var file;
  var name;
  var link;
  var row;
  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    link = file.getUrl();
    sheet.appendRow( [name, link] );     
  }  
};
```

Please Help.

Comment: I'm not sure what mean by list all of the files in your google sheets but yes you can access file in shared folders with Drives API.  You will need to enable it

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62311120/1595451

Comment: @Cooper how do i enable it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for one folder with the folder's ID

```
function listing() {
  var folderID = '_______folder_ID_here_______'
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow( ['name', 'link'] );
  var file;
  var name;
  var link;
  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    link = file.getUrl();
    sheet.appendRow( [name, link] );     
  }  
};
```

Comment: but i think this will only work for the folder that is associated with my google id. What if anyone has made his folder accessible publically and how do i list from that folder

Comment: This works well with a "foreign" folder for which you have received authorisation et know the id. Tested. Try with that ID = 1lVMeYvrbmrVYHBF0ekMe1uwNSONaSzjr

Comment: Thankyou. It is working. Thankyou very much @mike-steelson